# How to generate points in a sphere and plot them with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this method to give me a list of points inside a sphere. However when I plot the result it does not look spherical at all. There must be something wrong with the logic here. What could it be?

```
def give_sphere(x, y, z, r, num):
    """The distribution of dots in the sphere increases towards the center.
    Return: A List of Points (x,y,z) which are all inside the sphere."""
    points = []
    for i in range(0, num):
        factor = normedgauss()        # A value between 0 and 1 following a gaussian
        ir = r * factor
        ix = x + ir * np.cos(npi())
        iy = y + ir * np.sin(npi())
        iz = z + ir * np.cos(npi())
        points.append((ix, iy, iz))
    return points
```

This is the 3D plot:
[image]
Also I want to plot this list of points using pyplot in 3D. I can achieve that with the following code, but then I cannot add another point cloud for display in the same diagram. How will I do that?

```
def plot_sphere(points):
    x_list = [x for [x, y, z] in points]
    y_list = [y for [x, y, z] in points]
    z_list = [z for [x, y, z] in points]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)

    ax.scatter(x_list, y_list, z_list)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `npi()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer that method will give me a uniform random float from [0, 2*pi).

Comment: Try taking a large `num` and see if it has something to do with the density of points that you don't see a sphere at the moment.

Comment: @Tristan It does not look like a sphere to me. Especially when rotating the view, these few points near the edges of th epicture look very off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are generating the angle using uniformly distributed random numbers, and that's is not the case. The volume differential in 3D is something like `(dr^3)(d cos theta) (d phi)`, that means that the variable that is uniformly distributed is `cos theta`, not `theta` (same goes for the radial component, but I'm not sure what you are trying to to, so I left it untouched)

```
def give_sphere(x, y, z, r, num):
    points = []
    for i in range(0, num):
        factor = normedgauss()        # A value between 0 and 1 following a gaussian
        ir = r * factor
        itheta = np.arccos(np.random.uniform(-1, 1))
        iphi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
        ix = x + ir * np.sin(itheta) * np.cos(iphi)
        iy = y + ir * np.sin(itheta) * np.sin(iphi)
        iz = z + ir * np.cos(itheta)
        points.append((ix, iy, iz))
    return points
```

With this in mind, this is what you should get

[image]

As for the second problem

```
def plot_sphere(points, ax):
    x_list = [x for [x, y, z] in points]
    y_list = [y for [x, y, z] in points]
    z_list = [z for [x, y, z] in points]

    ax.scatter(x_list, y_list, z_list)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


points1 = give_sphere(0, 0, -2, 1, 1000)
points2 = give_sphere(0, 0, 2, 1, 1000)
plot_sphere(points1, ax)
plot_sphere(points2, ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I want the density of the points to increase, as the radian decreases. So I assume the current distribution (which is not uniform?) is good. As for the volume differential of a sphere, I did not know about this. That was causing the problem here.

Comment: As for `fig = plt.figure()`and `ax = Axes3D(fig)` I find it difficult to find much information on this. What exactly is the `fig` and the `ax`?

Comment: @PhilippWulff In a nutshell, `figure` is a container, where you put all your plot elements. `ax` is the axis, in this case is `3D` type

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is about Monte Carlo simulation based on a distribution function. Generally, one needs to derive a specific sampling scheme using the probability density function.

I assume you would like to have uniformly distributed points within a sphere. I would recommend one the best links which clearly demonstrates the whole process for your case and encourage you to explore the pros and cons:
[Generating uniformly distributed numbers on a sphere](http://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will look through it.